# powershell create multiple files from csv with specific content

Tags: powershell, csv, createfile

So, the problem is that I must create a 300 ini files. In CSV file I have a computer names and MAC addresses. Ini files must be named as MAC addresses. For that I have solution:

```
$data = Import-CSV d:\import.csv
ForEach ($i in $data){

$name = $i.name
$MAC = $i.MAC

New-Item -ItemType file -name $_.MAC.ini
}
```

But in this code I need to put some txt in those inies. For example:

```
some value
some text
some value=$_.name
and more txt
```

The content must have the name  of computer in some value which is in the same line as MAC address in CSV.

Here I need a help to do it. In first place I tried with Add-Content, but no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Import-CSV d:\import.csv | %{ 
    "some value`r`nsome text`r`nsome value=$($_.name)`r`nand more txt" | sc "$($_.MAC).ini" 
}
```

% is shorthand for Foreach-Object and sc is an alias for Set-Content.

Be sure your MAC addresses use dashes and not colons, since colons are invalid in filenames.

Comment: Thanks mate! You are my savior!